# Differences between self. and self._ in Python?

Tags: python

So when I call the variables from the `__init__`, are there any differences between using `self.` and `self._`? For example, it I define a variable x in `__init__` as `self._x`, when I need to call it in other functions, is it possible to call it by `self.x` and `self._x`? This confused me a lot, thanks.

Comment: [The meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Comment: The `_` is part of the property's name, along with the `x`, so `self.x` and `self._x` are entirely distinct from each other.

Comment: so in this case, if the variable in `__init__` is called `self._x`, I can only call it `self._x` in other functions and vice versa?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, The attribute's name.

Comment: @HuiTingKo, `self._x` works, at a technical level, the same as `self.x`. The difference is purely one of convention for programmers.

Comment: @MikeGraham, so it is correct to use `self._x` and `self.x` to call it if the x is assign to `self._x` only in `__init__`

Comment: @HuiTingKo, I can't understand what you are saying

Comment: @MikeGraham, so if there is a variable called `self._x` under the `__init__` function and I want to use it in other functions, can I use both `self._x` and `self.x`?

Comment: @HuiTingKo, No, `self._x` is `self._x`. It's completely unrelated to `self.x`. The difference between `self.x` and `self._x` is the same as the difference between `self.y` and `self.z` -- they're just different. Python doesn't magically convert at all. `self._x` doesn't really get special, magic treatment.